# Nagios/Icinga: different passwords for each NSClient++ host

Tags: nagios, nsclient++

Is it possible to pass a different password to the check_nt/check_nrpe command for each windows host I have defined in my icinga configs?
For example, I have 3 windows hosts

```
define host {
    use            windows-server
    host_name      prod
    address        10.0.0.1
}
define host {
    use            windows-server
    host_name      db
    address        10.0.0.2
}
define host {
    use            windows-server
    host_name      test
    address        10.0.0.3
}
```

and a service set up:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               prod,db,test
    service_description     Uptime
    check_command           check_nt!UPTIME
    normal_check_interval   180
    }
```

which calls

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nt
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -p 12489 -v '$ARG1$'
}
```

This is all working great but I want to be able to set a different password for each host (that isn't viewable from the web interface). I know that the USERn macro's don't appear in the web interface but I don't know how I could use them here.
Is there a simple way to do this without creating 3 different services and passing the password as an argument at that stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just rewrite the command definition:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nt_pwd
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -p 12489 -s '$ARG1$' -v '$ARG2$'
}
```

Then you can either use three service definitions like so:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               prod
    service_description     Uptime
    check_command           check_nt!PWD1!UPTIME
    normal_check_interval   180
    }
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               db
    service_description     Uptime
    check_command           check_nt!PWD2!UPTIME
    normal_check_interval   180
    }
```

Or if you have a modern Nagios set host variables (_password) and use a macro ($_HOSTPASSWORD$) like so:

```
define host {
    use            windows-server
    host_name      prod
    address        10.0.0.1
    _password      PWD1
}
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               prod,db,test
    service_description     Uptime
    check_command           check_nt!$_HOSTPASSWORD$!UPTIME
    normal_check_interval   180
    }
```

Or if you want add the macro directly to the command definition in a similar fashion.

Comment: The former violates your "that isn't viewable from the web interface" requirement, FYI. The latter should be okay.